# OpenCV Windows install: can not open file "OpenCV-2.4.5.exe" as archive

Tags: windows, opencv, installation

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I just want to install OpenCV for Windows on my Windows 7 (64-bit) platform. Did I download the wrong package or something? For reference, the file extension of what I downloaded came in .exe. I've also tried to change it to .7z which did not work (said the archive was corrupt).

What gives??

Comment: what's the size of it ? if it's only a few kb, chances are high that you saved the download link instead of the actual content

Comment: somewhere north of 250mb. Came as an .exe but apparently it wants to extract when I opened it. And that hasn't worked.

Comment: ah, ok. iirc, 2.4.3 was like 290 mb. still, your download might have been truncated. wget -c for the win!

Comment: Oh could you type out the full command I'd need to use for wget? Sorry, bit of a unix newbie. And of course if all goes well you can answer and I'll accept =)

Comment: Sorry didn't work, got the same .exe file.

Comment: any chance, you're using some pre-paid usb-stick-modem thingy, and your provider decided, you went over the cap ?

Comment: I hit the same problem as the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer is probably **corrupted**. Download it again, preferably using a *download manager*.